# User Profile 'Syntax Erro'r in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to create the user profile in Django. t is a new User model that inherits from AbstractUser. It requires special care and to update some references through the settings.py. Ideally, it should be done at the beginning of the project, since it will dramatically impact the database schema. Extra care while implementing it.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
        app_config.import_models()
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/home/user/Desktop/vmail/vm/models.py", line 21
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models, CASCADE)
                                                           ^
    SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument


how to solve this syntax error?

my models.py

    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


# Create your models here.
class login(models.Model):
      title=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
      content=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
      date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

      def __str__(self):
          return self.title

class UserProfileModel(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models, CASCADE)
      gender = models.CharField(max_length='1', choices=(('M','Male'),('F','Female')), blank=True)
      age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.user.username

      class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'Profile'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this to

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```